# How to convert pdb file to xml using mdbg?

Tags: pdb-files, mdbg

How to convert PDB file to XML file? I tried the source from [below](https://github.com/SymbolSource/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging/tree/master/src/tools/pdb2xml), but it's taking exe as an input. Is there any opensource converter available?

Answer (score 0):

The ISymbolReader interface from Microsoft needs a metadata token, which can be retrieved from the assembly using Reflection. I don't know a way to read the PDB on its' own - for my purposes, I always have the pdb and the assembly handy, so it hasn't been an issue for me.